# Is There a Short (One-Word) Name For a Comparison Operand?

Tags: computer-science, comparator, operands

I'm writing sorting routine that (of course) compares two objects.  In general, this breaks down to something of the form:

```
if( a < b ) ...
```

...where the less-than is the operator and a,b are the operands.  But in this case they're a pretty specific type of operand so I'm wondering if there's a special name for them.  The less-than would likely be called a Comparator.  Would a,b be Comperands?  Is there a special name for these already, or did my friend Satbir just invent one?

Comment: Mathematically it's an inequality which would make the two the LHS (Left hand side [of the inequality]) and the other side's name i forgot ;)

Comment: Looks like MSFT used "comperand" like one time in WinCE 5.0:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885667.aspx

Comment: ...AND if you spell it correctly ("comparand" instead of "comperand"), you get even more hits, including Wikitionary:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparand
http://tinyurl.com/glktyh5 (Google Books)

Comment: @BJBlack submit your response as the answer and I'll vote for it